# How to use readNet (or readFromDarknet) instead of readNetFromCaffe?

Tags: opencv, darknet, dotnetnuke, python

I did an object detection using opencv by loading pre-trained  MobileNet SSD model. [from this post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/13/opencv-people-counter/).
It reads a video and detects objects without any problem. But I would like to use `readNet` (or `readFromDarknet`) instead of `readNetFromCaffe`

`net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])`

because I have pre-trained weights and cfg file of **my own objects** only in Darknet framework. Therefore I simply changed `readNetFromCaffe` into `readNet` in **above post** and got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "people_counter.py", line 124, in <module>
    for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Here `detections` is an output from

```
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0/255.0, (416, 416), True, crop=False)
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()
```

Its shape is (1, 1, 100, 7) **tuple** (when using `readNetFromCaffe`).

I was kinda expecting it wouldn't work just by changing the model. Then I decided to look for an object detector code where `readNet` was used and  I found it [here](https://github.com/arunponnusamy/object-detection-opencv/blob/master/yolo_opencv.py). I read through the code and found the same lines as follows:

```
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, scale, (416,416), (0,0,0), True, crop=False)
net.setInput(blob)
outs = net.forward(get_output_layers(net))
```

Here, the shape of `outs` is (1, 845, 6) **list**. But in order for me to be able to use it right away ([here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/13/opencv-people-counter/)),   `outs` should be of the same size with `detections`. I've come up to this part and have no clue about how I should proceed.

If something isn't clear, I just need help to use `readNet` (or `readFromDarknet`) instead of `readNetFromCaffe` in [this post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/13/opencv-people-counter/)

Comment: for me it is not clear what you mean. Is your problem, that two network architectures are differen and so the output layer has to be interpreted differently?

Comment: @Micka I re-formatted the question, please, have a look

Comment: So you have the same network structure in caffe and darknet but they show different output shape in OpenCV? Which one of them "should" be right?

Comment: @hkchengrex I don't think they are (or should be) same. I am trying to use `readNet` (or `readFromDarknet`) instead of `readNetFromCaffe `.

Comment: @voo_doo It is not about how you read the model or what format the model is in. Ultimately there is an underlying network structure of the model which should be the same no matter which library you use. If you are not even using the same network structure, it would be natural that their output shape is not the same.

Comment: @hkchengrex, sure, I'm not claiming that they must be of same size, that's why I am here to ask how I can possibly use `readNet`. I am aware that Caffe and Darknet are different , so are their underlying networks. Here I showed up to which point I came and where the error occurred. _I am constantly editing the question to make it more clear_

Comment: Then you need to know the output format of your darknet model and that of the caffe model. Conversion is only possible after know the meaning of each element in the the two outputs.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the [code](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/13/opencv-people-counter/) closely we can see that everying is dependent on the outputs of `detections`, line 121, and we should tweak its outputs to match them with the `outs` of [this](https://github.com/arunponnusamy/object-detection-opencv/blob/66d6a4ff6da1a52cbb755b8a4eb7966d5b8fb452/yolo_opencv.py#L63), line 63. After spending almost a day, I came to a reasonable (not the perfect) solution. Basically, it is all about output blobs of  `readNetFromCaffe` and `readFromDarknet`, because they output a blob with a shape `1x1xNx7` and `NxC`, respectively. Here `N`s are the number of detections, but with different size vectors, namely, `N` in `1x1xNx7` is is a number of detections and an every detection is a vector of values
**[batchId, classId, confidence, left, top, right, bottom]** and `N` in `NxC` a number of
detected objects and C is a number of classes + 4 where the first 4 numbers are **[center_x, center_y, width, height]**. After analyzing these, we may replace (124-130 lines)

```
for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
    if confidence > args["confidence"]:
        idx = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
        if CLASSES[idx] != "person":
            continue
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
```

with equivalent lines

```
    for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[0]):
        scores = detections[i][5:]
        classId = np.argmax(scores)
        confidence = scores[classId]
        if confidence > args["confidence"]:
            idx = int(classId)
            if CLASSES[idx] != "person":
                continue

            center_x = int(detections[i][0] * 416)    
            center_y = int(detections[i][1] * 416)    
            width = int(detections[i][2] * 416)        
            height = int(detections[i][3] * 416)     
            left = int(center_x - width / 2)         
            top = int(center_y - height / 2)
            right = width + left - 1
            bottom = height + top - 1

            box = [left, top, width, height]
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
```

This way we can keep track of "person" class using Darknet's *cfg* and *weights* and count them up/down with a visualiation line.

Again, there might be some other more simpler ways of tracking the detections of Darknet weights file, but this works for this particular case.

**A reference:**
[more about blobs output by `readNetFromCaffe` and `readFromDarknet`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.3/samples/dnn/object_detection.py#L94-L150)